# Cofinite topology if first countable iff $X$ is countable

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

Here are two statements I want to show:

> For cofinite topology space $(X, \mathcal{T})$:
>
> (a)  Show that X is first countable if and only if X has countably many points.

I have known how to prove " if X is first countable then X has countably many points". I use the contradiction to find if $X$ is uncountable, we could not find a countable local base.

But how about the inverse statement? If $X$ is countable, suppose $X=\{x_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. For every $x_i$, I try to find their countable local basis. How to show that for every open set $U$, there exists a countable local basis $V_{i}$ such that $x\in V_i\subset U$? for some $i$.

> (b)  Show that X is second countable if and only if X has countably many points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is countable, it has only countably many finite sets (standard set theory, or use a mapping using prime numbers to show that all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$ are in bijection with $\Bbb N$, e.g.), so countably many closed sets, so countably many open sets.

The whole topology is then countable and is its own base, while (the also countable) subfamily, $\{O: O \in \mathcal{T}, x \in O\}$ is a local base at $x$, for any $x$.

As to the last question, $X$ uncountable implies $X$ not first countable and so $X$ not second countable, so it's the same argument.

Comment: I use contradiction to show the first claim. If not, for some uncountable index $I$ and finite sets $F_{\alpha}$, $\cup_{\alpha\in I}F_{\alpha}$ could be uncountable which is a contradiction( X is countable). Is it right?

Comment: @TYG you use contradiction to show $X$ uncountable implies it’s not first countable. You cannot prove in your suggested way that a countable set only has countably many finite sets.

Comment: So how to prove your claim: it has only countably many finite sets? I do not get your point. What is the map?

Comment: @TYG the only closed sets, besides $X$ itself, are the finite sets.

Comment: First question: why only countably many finite sets? Can I use the contradiction? All closed sets are finite sets. So all the subsets of topology are cofinite. Hence, the whole topology is all open sets.

Comment: @TYG a countable set has countably many finite subsets. So the cofinite topology on a countable set has countably many closed sets, and hence countably many open sets.

Comment: Don't need to prove"a countable set has countably many finite subsets"?

Comment: @TYG set theory fact; should be known.

Comment: Is the proof to use the bijection map between $X$ and $\mathbf{N}$? Since $\mathbf{N}$ has countably many finite subsets. So $X$ is the same?

Comment: @TYG yes, of course.